# Ubuntu 22.04 Network Manager removes OpenVPN connection TLS certificate

Tags: 22.04, network-manager, vpn, openvpn

Network Manager on Ubuntu 22.04 removes the OpenVPN connection TLS certificate after viewing the configuration. In *Settings* → *Network* → *VPN settings* → *Identity* → *Advanced* → *TLS Authentication*,
after clicking *Apply TLS*, mod and key files get reset.

Does anyone have a solution for this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Yep I have got this issue too. Trying to use network manager to set up a surfshark VPN.

You can download their server configurations like this:
`sudo wget https://my.surfshark.com/vpn/api/v1/server/configurations`

Then you can add a VPN using network manager and import the config data from a file as described in this article: https://support.surfshark.com/hc/en-us/articles/360012109779-Connect-to-Surfshark-VPN-using-Ubuntu-Network-Manager

If you close and open network manager, the TLS auth information persists. If you try connect to the VPN, the TLS auth info disappears. If you try restart the computer, it also disappears.